# Complete uninstall of python3.10

Tags: apt, 20.04, python, uninstall

I’m trying to uninstall Python 3.10.

I've tried both commands below:

```bsh
$ sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove python3.10
[sudo] password for henrique: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libqgispython3.10.4' for regex 'python3.10'
Note, selecting 'libpython3.10-stdlib' for regex 'python3.10'
Package 'libpython3.10-stdlib' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libqgispython3.10.4' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.

$ sudo apt-get remove python3.10
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libqgispython3.10.4' for regex 'python3.10'
Note, selecting 'libpython3.10-stdlib' for regex 'python3.10'
Package 'libpython3.10-stdlib' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libqgispython3.10.4' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 11 not upgraded.
```

But Python 3.10 remains installed.

```bsh
$ which python3.10
/usr/local/bin/python3.10

$ python3.10
Python 3.10.0 (default, Oct 23 2021, 15:04:26) [GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Should I remove everything related to `python3.10` in `/usr/local/bin/` folder?

PS: I've installed it from source, I don't know if that makes any difference.

Comment: You are using the wrong tool for the job: Apt-get ONLY knows about deb packages. Apt-get has never heard of installing from source, and deb-package tools cannot help you with that.

Comment: You can use the deadsnakes PPA to install (and subsequently uninstall) python3.10 in Ubuntu 20.04 in a painless manner. https://launchpad.net/~deadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"*Should I remove everything related to python3.10 in /usr/local/bin/ folder?*"

Yes, that is the correct way to manually remove software that you manually installed.

Be very careful if you have more than one application installed in that directory. You don't want to remove something that you actually wanted to keep.

Manually installing and uninstalling software can be tedious and error-prone. Sorry about that. Those are two of the reasons that folks migrated to packages and package managers.